# How to safely subslice a rust slice?

Tags: rust

On Rust you can subslice a slice/vector/etc

```
fn main() {
    let a = vec![0; 6];
    let b = &a[0..2];
    println!("{:?}", b);
}
```

however this panics if the range for which you're slicing is too big.

**Is there a safe way to subslice and get an option if the subslice succeeded or not?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`get()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.slice.html#method.get):

```rust
fn main() {
    let a = vec![0; 6];
    let b = a.get(0..2);
    println!("{:?}", b);
}
```